# Error while connecting to SQL Server from an UWP application

Tags: c#, sql-server, uwp, connection

I'm getting an error when trying to connect to SQL Server from the UWP application, I already have activated the capabilities:

- Internet (Client & Server)
- Internet (Client)
- Private Networks (Client & Server)

[image: Error window]

The code is the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace App1544
{
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        const string ConnectionString = "SERVER = DESKTOP-DI0OR53; database= DBNAVEGANTE; user id= root; password = a";
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
            {
                con.Open();
                label1.Text = con.State.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is the server running on the same machine as the uwp app? There are some restrictions for such scenarios in UWP. Maybe it has to do with that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/networking/sockets

Comment: Please try to add the **Enterprise Authentication** Capability in the Package.appxmanifest file of your UWP app.